# Call django custom management command in redis queue

Tags: django

Is it possible to call a django management command as a queued job in redis? This fails for me with:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from rq import Queue

queue = Queue(connection=redis_client)
job = queue.enqueue(call_command, 'elastic_update')
```

The error I get is: CommandError: Unknown command: 'elastic_update'. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? This same command works when I run it from the command line or with a shell.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing, same error . do you got it to work?

Comment: No sorry I think I refactored the code so I no longer needed that capability.