# Calling Django custom management command using Celery and Redis outputs "Unknown command" error

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I am trying to call a function asynchronously in Django using Celery and Redis as a message broker. I am calling a function that calls `call_command()` to execute a custom management command I made.

```
@app.task
def processVideo(url):
   management.call_command('analyzevideos', url)
```

However, calling `processVideo.delay(url)` produces the following error:

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'analyzevideos'
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring since calling `management.call_command('analyzevideos', url)` in the Python shell works perfectly fine.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765534/call-django-custom-management-command-in-redis-queue) that has no answers.

Comment: Do you create celery using the same django settings? Could you verify the app that has the `analyzevideos` command is listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` within `processVideo`?

Comment: @schillingt I'm not sure what you mean by "within `processVideo`" but when I look in `settings.py`, I do not have `analyzevideos` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. I don't think it should be there since it's a command, not an app. I have my `search` app in `INSTALLED_APPS` which contains my `analyzevideos` command.

Comment: Add `print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)` to the top of the `processVideo` function and verify that the `search` app is within that.

Comment: @schillingt Adding that print statement does not print anything out. It just says that a task has been received and them prints out `KeyError: 'analyzevideos'` (I forgot to mention this before) and `Unknown command: 'analyzevideos'`

Comment: @schillingt Just to clear up any confusion, if I remove the `@app.task` decorator and call it like `analyzevideo(url)`, I do see `search` in `setting.INSTALLED_APPS` but only if I import my settings like so: `from projname import settings`

Comment: The issue is that your celery workers are not setting up the django application. Please review the documentation: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django